# Change number of output files using DataFrameWriter in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataset that I'm writing out to S3 using the DataFrameWriter.  I'm using Parquet and also doing a partitionBy call on a column that has 256 distinct values.  It works well but takes some time to write the dataset out (and read into other jobs).  In debugging, I noticed that the writer only outputs 256 files, one per suffix, despite my `repartition` call specifying 256 partitions.  Is there a way to increase the number of files output for each partitionBy value?

My code looks like:

```
myDS = myDS.repartition(256, functions.col("suffix"));
myDS.write().partitionBy("suffix").parquet(String.format(this.outputPath, "parquet", this.date));
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue with my code was the presence of specifying a column in my `repartition` call.  Simply removing the column from the `repartition` call fixed the issue.

The relationship between number of output files per `partitionBy` value is directly related to the number of partitions.  Suppose you have 256 distinct `partitionBy` values.  If you precede your writer with a `repartition(5)` call, you'll end up with a maximum of 5 output files per `partitionBy` value.  Total number of output files would not exceed 1280 (though it could be less if a there is not much data for a given partitionBy value).